# PowerMock internal error: Should never throw exception at this level

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to run junit test case where I've mocked a static class using PowerMock but it's failing with below error. I've added powermock-api-mockito2 and powermock-module-junit4 dependencies of version 2.0.0 (tried with 2.0.9). Prior to adding PowerMock junit was running fine. This looks like some internal error and not related to test case.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: PowerMock internal error: Should never throw exception at this level
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.handleException(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:384)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:110)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:117)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected native java.lang.Object java.lang.Object.clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @6e6f2380
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doGetAllMethods(WhiteboxImpl.java:1499)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getAllMethods(WhiteboxImpl.java:1473)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.findMethodOrThrowException(WhiteboxImpl.java:853)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:813)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:681)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.handleException(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:361)
    ... 20 more
```

Below is the code from Test class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
//@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebFluxTest(EmployeeService.class)
public class EmployeeServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    
    @MockBean
    private IEmployeeDAO iEmployeeDAO;
    
    @PrepareForTest(MappingDtoToEntity.class)
    //@Test
    public void createEmployeeTest() {

        List<AddressDTO> addressDTOList= new ArrayList<>(); 
        addressDTOList.add(new AddressDTO("address"));
        List<Address> addressList= new ArrayList<>(); 
        addressList.add(new com.springflexcounchdb.model.Address("address"));
        EmployeeDTO employeeDTO= new EmployeeDTO("1", "1", "1-1234", "Test-Employee", 20, addressDTOList);
        employeeDTO.setCreatedBy(CommonUtils.CREATED_BY);
        employeeDTO.setCreatedOn(CommonUtils.CREATED_DATE);
        employeeDTO.setLastModifiedBy(CommonUtils.LAST_MODIFIED_BY);
        employeeDTO.setLastModifiedOn(CommonUtils.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE);
        employeeDTO.setStatus(new Short("1"));
        
        Employee employee = new Employee("1", "1", "1-1234", "Test-Employee", 20, addressList);
//      employee.setCreatedBy(CommonUtils.CREATED_BY);
//      employee.setCreatedOn(CommonUtils.CREATED_DATE);
//      employee.setLastModifiedBy(CommonUtils.LAST_MODIFIED_BY);
//      employee.setLastModifiedOn(CommonUtils.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE);
//      employee.setStatus(new Short("1"));
        Mono<String> id = Mono.just("{\"_id\":\"701660a57b8d95b466211de348007397\"}");
        
        mockStatic(MappingDtoToEntity.class);
        
        when(MappingDtoToEntity.convertEmployeeEntity(employeeDTO)).thenReturn(employee);
        when(iEmployeeDAO.create(employee)).thenReturn(id);
        Mono<String> response  = employeeService.create(employeeDTO);
        
        verifyStatic(MappingDtoToEntity.class, times(1));
        assertEquals(id, response);
    }
}
```